# Weighted maximum likelihood estimator for poisson variables

Tags: poisson-distribution, maximum-likelihood, log-likelihood

I have been learning about the E-M algorithm in the Normal case. I would like to create the algorithm with two Poisson variables. To do so, I need to calculate the weighted MLE as seen [here](https://blackboard.gwu.edu/bbcswebdav/pid-9306832-dt-content-rid-61048911_2/courses/46683_201901/EM.html) in the M-Step. I have tried a number of techniques but my code shows I am doing this completly wrong. Any ideas?

Ideally I can recreate this "M-Step" for my setting by calculating this MLE.